# How to initialise all TabBarView on start in Flutter

Tags: flutter

I have a page with two tabs bar, with the image below:

[image]

This is a filter page that when the user types what he wants to find in the input text, both Tabs will load a list.

Tab one is Store filter and Tab two is Product filter, the problem is that Tab from flutter only initiates the **initState()** if the user scroll to the Tab.

In **initState()** from both I have an observable that is listening when the user types a new search. Here is the initState:

```
  @override
  void initState() {
    super.initState();
    companyService = Provider.of<CompanyService>(context, listen: false);
    filterService = Provider.of<FilterService>(context, listen: false);
    companyService.loadFilter$.listen((value) {
      loadFilterListData(value);
      searchContent = value;
    });
    _scrollController.addListener(() {
      if (_scrollController.position.pixels ==
          _scrollController.position.maxScrollExtent) {
        if (resetData) {
          resetData = !resetData;
          loadMoreDataFilterList(searchContent);
        }
      }
    });
  }
```

My TabBarView code:

```
 Expanded(
        child: TabBarView(
          controller: _tabController,
          children: [
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                  top: 15.0, left: 10.0, right: 10.0),
              child: CompanyFilteredList(),
            ),
            Padding(
              padding: const EdgeInsets.only(
                  top: 15.0, left: 10.0, right: 10.0),
              child: ProductFilterGrid(),
            ),
          ],
        ),
      ),
```

How can I initiate **initState()** from both Tab's when the user enters this page? Not just the Tab he is in?

Comment: `"How can I initiate initState()"` - what do you mean by that? you want to call `initState()`? or something else?

Comment: I update my question to you see @pskink, I have two widgets in my TabBarView, the problem is when the user for the first time go to this page, only the select tab initiate, the other tab will initiate only if the user clicks on the tab. But I need both initiates on the first time that the page loads it, why I want that? Is because they have on iniState() an observable that I need to be executed.

Comment: I test it and i put this AutomaticKeepAliveClientMixin on my two widgets and is working fine if the user goes to the other tab. So I make a small modification temporarily working on my iniState() from the main widget, that I go to second tab and go to the first one, it is a temporary solution.